# How to improve speed for couting a BigInteger to 2^256

Tags: c#, biginteger, largenumber

this small console application count a BigInteger and give me a feedback which exponent it hits.

Now I'm curious for some speed improvments. What can I do?

Thx for your suggestions!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;

namespace Counter
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<BigInteger, int> Dic = new Dictionary<BigInteger, int>();

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start with counting ... from 1 to 2^256.");
            Console.WriteLine();

            CreateDict();

            var bigInteger = new BigInteger();

            Console.WriteLine("D:HH:mm:ss,ms      - fac.  - Number");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");

            var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            while (true)
            {
                bigInteger++;
                if (Dic.ContainsKey(bigInteger))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0:G} - 2^{1,3} = {2:#,0}", (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime), Dic[bigInteger], bigInteger);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void CreateDict()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 256; i++)
            {
                Dic.Add(BigInteger.Pow(2, i), i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output: http://pastebin.com/bMBntFsL

**Progress**

Working with BigInteger was not so good.

BigInteger 2^26 = 5s

Double 2^26 = 1,3s

Switching from Dict to direct compare was much faster to

```
            int i = 1;
            double pow = Math.Pow(2, i);
            while (true)
            {
                bigInteger++;
                if (bigInteger == pow)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0:G} - 2^{1,3} = {2:#,0}", (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime), Dic[bigInteger], bigInteger);

                    i++;
                    pow = Math.Pow(2, i);
                }
            }
```

Dict 2^26 = 1,3s

"<" 2^26 = 0,5s

Comment: Not clear what you are asking or trying to achieve here. Why do you count at all?

Comment: Just playing around with BigInteger and i stock with ideas for speed improvments. Is a Dictionary the best way? If ContainsKey faster than run into a exception by Dic[bigInteger].

Comment: Dictionary is not the problem at all, why you have to increment bigInteger by 1?

Comment: The dictionary is fine. Using exceptions instead of `ContainsKey` is way slower, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101795/why-is-it-faster-to-check-if-dictionary-contains-the-key-rather-than-catch-the/16101815#16101815).

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to count up to 2^256 in a loop, do not use `BigInteger`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) :

> > The other numeric types in the .NET Framework are also immutable. However, because the BigInteger type has no upper or lower bounds, its values can grow extremely large and have a measurable impact on performance.
> >
> > Although this process is transparent to the caller, it does incur a **performance penalty**. In some cases, **especially when repeated operations are performed in a loop** on very large BigInteger values, that performance penalty can be **significant**

Since your desired value is big but not *incredibly big*, you can use a [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead. `double` value can go up to `1.7 × 10^308`, so you're fine with 2^256 (which is `1.15 × 10^77`). That should help a lot with the performance of your application.

---

An other improvement would be to use `TryGetValue` for your dictionary instead of `ContainsKey`, as you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382740/2316200).

Because you're doing both `ContainsKey(bigInteger)` and `Dic[bigInteger]` you're doing the lookup twice.

So the code would become :

```
while (true)
{
    bigValue++;

    int exponent;
    if (Dic.TryGetValue(bigValue, out exponent))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0:G} - 2^{1,3} = {2:#,0}", (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime), exponent, bigValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: But the secound lookup is only when I hit an exponent.

Comment: @user1776231 You're still doing the job twice. And using a nicely named temp variable is cleaner than the Dic[bigInteger] in my opinion.

Comment: It is true that a `double` can very easily hold the value `Pow(2, 256)` (which is `1.157920892373162E+77`). But it is not true that you can "count" from `0.0` to `Pow(2, 256)` with a `double` by incrementing with `++`. A `double` has a precision of only approximately 16 decimal figures. So if you take for example `d = 1E+18;` and try to increase it with `d++`, you will see that the number doesn't change. There is a "step" of `128` from `1E+18` to the next representable `double` which is `1.000000000000000128E+18`.

Comment: Is it just me or does nobody here realize that running a counter from zero to 2^256 is physically impossible?